# SharedPreferences in picking random value when force closing application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have to implement a functionality in which I have to store multiple id's in SharedPreferences in an application in android. I have to perform three main operations on data in preferences
1. add and save new id
2. delete a particular id
3. check if id exists

I wrote following class to perform all operations needed.

```
public class PreferenceUtils {

    Context context;
    private static final String TAG = PreferenceUtils.class.getName();

    private static final String FAVOURITES = "favourites";

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public PreferenceUtils(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = preferences.edit();

    }

    public void save(long id) {
        Set<String> prefStrings = preferences.getStringSet(FAVOURITES, new HashSet<String>());
        prefStrings.add(id+"");
        editor.putStringSet(FAVOURITES, prefStrings);
        editor.commit();
        editor.clear();
        Log.d(TAG,id + " saved");
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        Set<String> prefStrings = preferences.getStringSet(FAVOURITES, new HashSet<String>());
        prefStrings.remove(id + "");
        editor.putStringSet(FAVOURITES, prefStrings);
        editor.commit();
        editor.clear();
        Log.d(TAG,id + " deleted");
    }

    public boolean isExists(long id) {
        final Set<String> prefStrings = preferences.getStringSet(FAVOURITES, new HashSet<String>());
        return prefStrings.contains(id+"");
    }

    public Set<String> getAll() {
        return preferences.getStringSet(FAVOURITES, new HashSet<String>());
    }

    public void clearHistory() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

I am creating instance of PreferenceUtils class from MainActivity like this:

```
PreferenceUtils pref = new PreferenceUtils(getApplicationContext());
```

Now the problem is when I am saving few values in preferences and closing application using back button or a Quit button (which will finish() MainActivity) everything is working fine and I am getting all the values from preferences. However, if I am force closing the application and reopening it I am getting only the first value I saved and rest all values are lost.

Comment: I would suggest that you perform the updates as soon as possible; i.e., as soon as something changes that requires an update, instead of waiting until `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` is called. There's really nothing you can do if Android decides to abruptly terminate your process.

Comment: I am actually saving and deleting as soon as getting call to onClickListener. May be android kind of caches shared preferences somehow. I need to read more on how shared preferences work. I'll try to look at source code of editor and see what its doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the editor.clear() in both save and delete.this might be your problem.